# Передача props между компонентами в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

У меня есть несколько компонентов по сути никак не связанных между собой, первый это ShoppingCards

```js
import { sample } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
import React from 'react';
import ShoppingCard from './ShoppingCard';
import goods from './goods.json';

export default class ShoppingCards extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);
        this.shoppingCardsJSX = goods.map((good) => {
            return (
                <ShoppingCard
                    key = {good.id }
                    goodId = {good.id}
                    src = {good.src}
                    descr = {good.descr}
                    code = {good.code}
                    size = {good.size}
                    color = {good.color}
                    price = {good.price}
                    onRemoveCard={this.removeCard.bind(this)
                    }
                />
            );
        });
    }
    removeCard(obj){
        const list = this.shoppingCardsJSX ;
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            if (list[i].key === obj){                
                list.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        this.forceUpdate();     
    }
    render() {
        return this.shoppingCardsJSX;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Второй это SearchBlock.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import main_logo from '../images/logo-main.png';
import ShoppingCard from './ShoppingCard'

class SeekBlock extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <label htmlFor={this.props.id}>
                <input type = "text" placeholder="Поиск по сайту" className={this.props.className} id = {this.props.id}/>
            </label>
        )
    }
}
export default class SearchBlock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.spanObject = { userName: 'Анастасия'};
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <div className="search-block">
             <img className="main-logo" src = {main_logo} alt ={this.props.className}/>
             <div className="seek-block">
                <SeekBlock className="search-string" id = "search"/>
             </div>
             <div className="account-block">
                 <div className="user-info user-info--name">
                    <a className="user-info__user-name" href="/">{this.spanObject.userName}</a>
                 </div>
                 <div className="user-info user-info--user-bucket">
                     <a className="user-info__bucket" href="/" >В корзине: 4 <br/> товара</a>
                 </div>
             </div>
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**Проблема в том, что мне нужно, чтобы длина массива this.shoppingCardsJSX.length из ShoppingCards как-то попала в SearchBlock, что-то вроде:**

```
<a className="user-info__bucket" href="/" >В корзине: {this.shoppingCardsJSX.length} <br/> товара</a>
```

и каждый раз обновлялась в зависимости от длинны массива.

Компонент ShoppingCards импортится в компонент ShoppingList, ShoppingList импортится в MainContent, а MainContent импортится в ShopPage. 
Компонент SearchBlock сразу импортится в ShopPage.

Никак не могу с этим разобраться, помогите пожалуйста. Прочитала похожие решения на стеке, но ни одно из них не получилось реализовать. Возможно ли это вообще сделать без redux?

Comment: `this.forceUpdate()` ай ай ай плохо так делать

Comment: `shoppingCardsJSX` зачем вы тут храните сразу компоненты? почему бы в рендере не писать массив, которые будет уже добавлять компоненты, вместо того что бы пихать все в св-во

Comment: если компоненты ничего не знают друг о друге, то они должны общаться через общего родителя или опять же какой-нибудь `state-managment`, можно в сторону контекста посмотреть, если используете последнюю версию реакта

Answer (score 1):

сделайте родительский компонент который будет получать goods.json и хранить у себя в state

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { goods: JSON.parse(goods.json) }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <ShoppingCards goods={this.state.goods} />
        <SearchBlock goodsLength={this.state.goods.length} />
      <React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Это не самый оптимальный вариант но он вполне подходит... а вообще поставьте себе mobx и у вас будет доступ к состоянию в любой точке приложения